# Create a new column using str.contains and where the condition fails, set it to null (NaN)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in my pandas dataframe, but only with a value if another column contains a certain string.

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
    raw                                     val1    val2  
0   Vendor Invoice Numbe Inv Date                        
1   Vendor: Company Name 1                  123     456   
2   13445 07708-20-2019 US                  432     676   
3   79935 19028808-15-2019 US               444     234   
4   Vendor: company Name 2                  234     234
```

I am trying to create a new column, `vendor` that transforms the dataframe into:

```
    raw                                     val1    val2  vendor
0   Vendor Invoice Numbe Inv Date                         Vendor Invoice Numbe Inv Date
1   Vendor: Company Name 1                  123     456   Vendor: Company Name 1 
2   13445 07708-20-2019 US                  432     676   NaN
3   79935 19028808-15-2019 US               444     234   NaN
4   Vendor: company Name 2                  234     234   company Name 2  
5   Vendor: company Name 2                  928     528   company Name 2
```

However, whenever I try,

`df['vendor'] = df.loc[df['raw'].str.contains('Vendor', na=False), 'raw']`

I get the error

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I know that at index 4 and 5 it's the same value for the company, but what am I doing wrong and how to I add the new column to my dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `df.loc[df['raw'].str.contains('Vendor', na=False), 'raw']` as different length than `df`.

You can try `np.where`, which assigns a new columns by an `np.array` of the same size, so it doesn't need index alignment.

```
df['vendor'] = np.where(df['raw'].str.contains('Vendor'), df['raw'], np.NaN)
```

Comment: is `loc`/slice assignment aligned on index? so, even `df.loc[df['raw'].str.contains('Vendor', na=False), 'raw']` has different length, it is still a slice from `df`. Therefore, the assignment should work?

Comment: assignment with `loc` should still work with normal index. Since the error was `reindex`, I thought `np.where` could go around that problem.

Comment: I ask because you say the issue is different length. `df.loc[df['raw'].str.contains('Vendor', na=False), 'raw']` is a slice from `df`. So its index is the sub-index of `df`. He assigns it to the new column `vendors` of `df` through `.__setitem__`. It should work without problem. I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: This doesn't take into account stripping away the `Vendor: ` part of the string.

Comment: @jorijnsmit I can handle that in a different step. This is just one step in converting a pdf files to tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the part of the string that comes after `Vendor:` using a positive lookbehind:

`df['vendor'] = df['raw'].str.extract(r'(?<=Vendor:\s)(.*)')`